Sealing Corner Between New and Old Siding
I need to seal the gap between the old siding and the new. I need to replace all the siding, but would like to avoid that for a couple years. It’s probably going to be a major project because doing this side of the house involved replacing two rotting posts and there's evidence there may be more around the rest of the house. The new side is Hardie board and PVC trim fastened with stainless steel screws. The old side is vinyl siding and has a partial corner piece attached. It was cut off leaving the j-channel portion. I watched a YouTube video on replacing a corner piece for vinyl siding. I was thinking buy a corner piece, cut the j-channel off one side, attach the cut side to the old cut off j-channel, then remove the PVC trim and fasten it back with the non-cut j-channel part under the PVC trim (in-between PVC trim and green board? behind the green board?) Is that the easiest way to seal this corner? And I have no idea what to do at the top where the soffit ends.



Some retail siding stores also do custom bending. Measure out what you so that it tucks in behind both sections. You may have to pop rivet in the section under the eave and at the top.
